# React Native code....panGestureHandler is not working (onGestureEvent is not trigerred) in the code below

Tags: react-native

I am working on an expo based react native code.  The intention is to support animations based on gestures.  The code is below.  I am implementing the logic using PanGestureHandler.  However, it seems that it is not triggered at all....

This is the code...any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  withSpring,
  useSharedValue,
  useDerivedValue,
  runOnJS,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { GestureHandlerRootView, PanGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { WORD_HEIGHT, MARGIN_LEFT, width, MARGIN_TOP } from "../../../Constants";
import React from "react";

export default (props) => {
  const {offsets, index, children, containerWidth} = props

  const offset = offsets[index];
  const isGestureActive = useSharedValue(false);
  const isAnimating = useSharedValue(false); 
  const translation = {x:useSharedValue(0),y:useSharedValue(0)};

  const translateX = useDerivedValue(() => {
    if (isGestureActive.value) return translation.x.value;
    
    return offset.originalX.value
  });
  const translateY = useDerivedValue(() => {
    if (isGestureActive.value) return translation.y.value;

    return offset.originalY.value;
  });


  const style = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      //zIndex: isGestureActive.value || isAnimating.value ? 100 : 0,
      width: offset.width.value,
      height: WORD_HEIGHT,
      transform: [
        { translateX: translateX.value - ( width / 2) },
        { translateY: translateY.value },
      ]
    };
  });
  
  const panGestureEvent = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: (_, ctx) => {
      console.log("Start")
    runOnJS(console.log)(isGestureActive.value)
      ctx.startX = translation.x.value;
      ctx.startY = translation.y.value;
      isGestureActive.value = true;
    },
    ....

  return <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex:1}}>
    <Animated.View style={style}>
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={panGestureEvent}>
        <Animated.View style={[style, StyleSheet.absoluteFill]}>
          {children}
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </Animated.View>
  </GestureHandlerRootView>
}
```

I inserted console.logs in useAnimatedGestureHandler but nothing is displaying in the console when gesture is made...

Comment: In relation to the above, and really not seeing that PanGestureHander is being trigerred, I started with a fresh install of Expo..and according to documentations, I did the following:1. npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler 2. npx expo install react-native-reanimated...all folliwing the docs......and I have the following code:   ```const panGesture = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart:()=>{
      console.log('onStart')
    },
    onActive:()=>{console.log('onActive')},
    onEnd:()=>{console.log('onEnd')}
  })```.......no print on the console......what could be the prob here